# Does SonarQube 5.4's 'Sonar way' quality profile contain Findbugs?

Tags: sonarqube, findbugs, sonarqube5.3

There was saying that 'SonarQube Java Analyzer'  will be containing FindBug rules  .so we need not to add any external findbug rule to sonar .

http://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-java-analyzer-the-only-rule-engine-you-need/

Is this already added in SonarQube 5.4 ?

Thanks

Ganesh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you should focus here is not the version of SonarQube but version of SonarQube Java Analyzer. Last release of the analyzer (3.12 at time of writing) contains rules that cover more than 80% of findbugs rules and this coverage is likely to keep increasing.

So yes, by updating to the latest version of SonarQube and the java analyzer, you don't need to use the FindBugs plugin anymore.
(Disclaimer, I am maintainer of the SonarQube java plugin, and author of the mentioned blog post in the question so I am a bit biaised here ;) )